# is there a ring $K$ such that it does not contain any prime belong to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $K$ be a ring  and let $L$ be the extension ring of $K$ given by $L=K(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$

Question 1: Is there a ring  $L$ such that it does not have any prime element belong to $\mathbb{Z}$ $(2,3,5,7,11,13,\ldots\notin P_L $ where $ P_L $ is the set of the prime element of $L$).

Question 2 : is there a ring  $L$  in which if $p \in P_{L}$ then $ p\nmid n $ for any integer $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ (or a lest some particular residue class like $n \equiv a \bmod d $ for some $a, d \in \mathbb{N} $ ?

Question 3: Is there a ring which satisfies question 1 and 2 at the same time?

Comment: What is meant by a "prime element" of a field? The usual definition of a prime element of a ring is that $p$ is prime if the principal ideal $(p)$ is a non-zero prime ideal, equivalently $p\neq 0$ and if $p\mid ab$, then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$. Under this definition, fields have no prime elements at all!

Comment: $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ then $pO_K$ is never a prime ideal. This is because the Galois group doesn't contain any $4$-cycle.

Comment: @reuns what is the question that you answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on the comment of @reuns. I will assume that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subring of your '$K$' (although I am going to change this notation) otherwise the question doesn't make sense. If I interperate your first question correctly then the answer is 'yes'.

Consider the ring $A = \mathbb{Z}$ and the ring $B = \mathcal{O}_K$ where $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$. Explicitly we may write $B = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}]$.

My argument requires a bit of number theory - perhaps someone can find an elementary argument. When $p = 2$ or $3$ it is easy to see that $2B = (\sqrt{2})^2$ and similarly for $3$, so we may assume that $p$ is unramified in $K$.

Take some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $B$ lying above $p$. We know that $p$ is inert (i.e., $pB$ is prime) if and only if the decomposition group $D_{\mathfrak{p}/p} \subset \operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$ is the entire group . But $p$ is unramified, so $D_{\mathfrak{p}/p}$ is isomorphic to the galois group of the extension of reside fields, which of course is cyclic (since the residue fields are finite). From this we see that $pB$ cannot be a prime ideal for any prime $p$ of $\mathbb{Z}$.

The answer to the second is 'No'. If $\pi$ is a prime element of a ring $B \supset \mathbb{Z}$ then $(\pi) \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is a prime ideal. In particular $p \in (\pi)$ for some prime $p$.

A few points on your post: $K$ and $L$ are normally reserved for fields we tend to use $A$, $B$, $R$ etc., for rings. If $A$ is a ring and you write $A(x)$ you are implicitly adjoining inverses too.

Comment: in the second question you said no in general but in a particular case can we get the intersection is just one prime or finite of them, for example, $ (\pi) \cap \mathbb{Z} = 2 $ where $\pi $ is prime of $B$ do you have an example of a case like this

Comment: @Abdo $(\pi)\cap \mathbb{Z}$ is prime, hence will always be an ideal generated by exactly one prime $p$. In particular $\pi$ divides some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $p \vert n$